# Headers and details from database tables

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I need an editor to create some reports, all reports have header (company name, address, phone, image) that is read from a table called companies and have a detailed, example all customers of the company.

How could I do this in iReports?

Is there any way to link two tables (company and customer) in my report? because the "report query" only allows me a sentence.

I work with Java Swing and MySql database.

Thanks for your helpful comments.

[image: Report example]

Comment: `Is there any way to link two tables (company and customer) in my report?` What do you mean? Do you need two grids or what?

Answer (score 1):

> I need an editor to create some reports, all reports have header (company name, address, phone, image) that is read from a table called companies and have a detailed, example all customers of the company. How could i do this in iReports?

You can look at [this samples](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html). The [JasperReports distribution package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.5.0/) contains many others samples (in folder *%jasperreports%\demo\samples*). The *iReport* has also several samples in folder *%iReport%\ireport\samples*.

Your sample report is very simple.

The steps for creating the such report can be like this:

1. Adding *image* element (with company logo) and several (or one) *staticText* elements (with company contact information) to the *Title* band.
2. Adding query (for getting data from *MySQL* DB) with fields (*idClient*, *name*, *address* in your sample)
3. Adding *staticText* elements with columns header to the *Column header* band - it will be the columns header for data grid
4. Adding *textField* elements with fields to the *Detail* band - it will be the data in grid

You should read the *[JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)*. It is a great tutorial.

The sample *jrxml* file (designed in *iReport*):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sample_company" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT idClient, name, address FROM customers_table]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="idClient" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="108" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="171" y="53" width="183" height="55"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled"/>
                <text><![CDATA[<style isBold="true" forecolor="blue">ABC COMPANY</style>
Main Avenue and 9th Street
Tel: (593)  4 - 2066765
e-mail: info@abc.com]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="245" y="3" width="41" height="50"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["abc_logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="160" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Id Client]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="171" y="0" width="183" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="354" y="0" width="172" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="11" y="0" width="160" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idClient}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="354" y="0" width="172" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="171" y="0" width="183" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (the report exported to *pdf* format):

[image: The report in PDF format]

***UPDATE:***

For filling header with company info you can use the *Group* band. You can read info about groups [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups).

You query will be like this:

```sql
SELECT c.idClient, c.name, c.address, cmp.name AS companyName, cmp.contactInfo, cmp.id AS idCompany FROM customers c, companies cmp WHERE cmp.id=c.idCompany SORT BY cmp.id
```

You should also add report's *fields* for data from *`companies`* table (*`companies.name`*, *`companies.contactInfo`*, *`companies.id`*, for example):

```
    <field name="companyName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="contactInfo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="idCompany" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

After that you should add *group* by *`idCompany`* (the unique key from *`companies`* table).
And then put the *textField* elements with fields (*`companyName`*, *`contactInfo`*) to the *Group* band.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but the header is not static text, the header and detail are dinaymic with information from database tables